# How do I join three tables in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, select, join

Three Tables:
Brand
Product
Sales

Sales and product is connected but brand isn't connected to Sales.
Brand is only connected to Product.

Which join do I use? An example would be great with random column names so I can attempt it

Comment: This is not the right forum for a tutorial on using SQL.

Comment: -1  You need to use Google and find a beginner's tutorial on SQL/mySQL or , at least, read the mySQL manual. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help..

Comment: If two tables are not related (you say so) how are you supposed to join them?

Answer (score 1):

You can have several `join` clauses, thus building the relationship between the tables incrementally (just guessing about your columns names):

```
SELECT *
FROM   brand b
JOIN   product p ON b.id = p.brand_id
JOIN   sales s ON p.id = s.product_id
```

Answer (score -1):

Joining three tables is similar to joining two tables, just join the first two tables, then add in the third in a second join.  I'll use your table names in an example assuming sales and product share a sale_id column and brand and product share a brand_id column.

```
SELECT *
FROM product JOIN sales USING(sale_id) JOIN brand USING(brand_id);
```

Any type of join can be used in this way, further using parenthesis to join tables in more complex ways.  There is also no limit on the number of tables you can join.  The question has been asked many times before, so next time, I recommend doing a bit more research before asking a question.

Comment: Using is not a type of join. It's just a shorthand notation if the joined fields have the same name in both tables

Comment: @LelioFaieta Thank you for your input.